# Error with on click view

Tags: android

In my app i need to show dialogs for a lot of buttons. Therefore i decided to use 1 onClick for a series of buttons. Only the first line where we implement, there is an error. My code is as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
public class Trial extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View b1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);  
        View b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);  
    }
    View.OnClickListener yourListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == button1) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                        .setTitle("Paracettamol")
                        .setMessage(
                                "This medicine is generally used to cure Fever")
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
            } else if (v == button2) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                        .setTitle("sertraline")
                        .setMessage(
                                "This medicine is generally used to cure Head aches")
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
            }


        }
    }
```

The fifth line(public class Trial extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener ) gives an error as follows:The type trial must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View). can anyone please help me.

Comment: Wow, you should check your code indentation! :) You can indent a line by prepending four spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the following in your class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- have your activity implement `View.OnClickListener`, that means moving `public void onClick(View v)` in the activity
- remove `implements View.OnClickListener` and call `b1.setOnClickListener(yourListener);`

Answer (score 1):

You've got two onClickListeners.
When you say:
`class Trial extends Activity implements onClickListener`,
You're declaring that the class `Trial` must itself respond to clicks. You therefore need to implement the onClick() method as in Jon's answer.

However, you've also made an internal `onClickListener`, called `yourListener`. If you want to use this one, you need to point your buttons to it instead of  `this`, which refers to the parent class. E.g:
`b1.setOnClickListener(yourListener);`